# Directive width in pixels

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs

I've been trying to determine the width of an element I'm declaring a directive on.

This is my directive link function:

```
link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
    var width = elem.width();
    scope.zoom = width / 674;
}
```

The element's width is 100% of the parent's width. I'm trying to get the width my element has when the entire page has finished loading and rendering, including this directive. I can see in my element-inspector it does eventually define the width in pixels, just not during any stage of my angular process.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Note:** I've already tried many different approaches using $timeout, but none of them delay the process long enough for the width to be set in pixels.

**Update 1:**

I was mistaken in thinking I'm using *ui-router*. I apparently use Angular's *ngRoute*. (I should really know these things, my bad).

In any case, none of the proposed solutions so far have yielded diserable results. Even some of the official Docs on jQuery have turned out not to be as concise as they'd like to think, so I figure I'll just share more of my code in hopes of finding out the problem.

Here is the full directive after my latest attempt:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app.widgets').directive('pagePreview', pagePreviewer);

    pagePreviewer.$inject = ['$window'];

    function pagePreviewer($window) {
        return {
            transclude: true,
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
                    scope.zoom = elem[0].clientWidth / 674;
                });

                //watch window resize
                angular.element($window).bind('resize', function () {
                    scope.zoom = elem[0].clientWidth / 674;
                    scope.$apply();
                });
            },
           templateUrl: 'app/widgets/pagePreviewer/pagePreviewer.html'
        }
    }
})();
```

The resize function works just fine, but the *$viewContentLoaded* event never fires.

My template is as follows:

```
<div>
    <style>
        .ft-page-container{
            position: relative;
            width:100%;
            padding-bottom:141%;
            border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
            box-shadow: 3px 3px 8px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }
        .ft-page-container .ft-page{
            position: absolute;
            top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
            background-color: white;
            padding: 12% 14%;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="ft-page-container">
        <div data-ng-transclude class="ft-page" style="zoom: {{zoom}}; -moz-transform: scale({{zoom}});">
            <!-- Html gets injected here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I use the directive inside an *ngView*, in the following context:

```
<!-- Preview -->
<div>
    <div id="invoice-template-preview" page-preview class="col-lg-offset-9 col-lg-3">
        Test
    </div>
</div>
```

I feel like I'm doing something very basic wrong, since it can't possibly this hard to obtain the computed CSS/dimension on a directive. Especially because following the Angular way tells you to always do DOM manipulation in directives, which most often heavily relies on said computed values.

Comment: are you using ui-router? if so you could try using $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded'.

Comment: Is your website responsive?

Comment: Yes to both questions. I just tried to use $scope in my directive but somehow it doesn't recognise it. I've injected it as usual but angular throws the unknown provider error.

Edit: $scope can't be used in a directive, and you're required to use either the parent's scope, the directive's own scope or $rootScope. None of these fire $viewContentLoaded though, so that's not much help.

Comment: Any feedback or suggestions?

Comment: @lin unfortunately, no. I ended up predetermining the width in my controller and passing it to the directive as a scope parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - the actual element you want to examine is the first object in the containing `elem`. The only downside of this is when the width is reported it does not include the 2px of the border (1px on each side). I put it insided a `$timeout` to ensure that it has rendered, but it may not technically be necessary.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('myDirective', function($timeout) {
    return {
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        $timeout(function() {
          console.log(elem[0].clientWidth)
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div style="width:100%; height: 50px; border: 1px solid black;" my-directive></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can see this working in your code snippet, but for me the exact same link function returns 0 as the width.

Comment: What kind of element are you putting your directive on?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [working plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/VUC0Ui3sEvxAu1sJJaul?p=preview) of what you try to achieve (*for example call Page1*). `$scope.zoom` will be updated when `$viewContentLoaded` was fired and also when `$window` size changed.

#### State1 view

```
<div>
     <div>
         <h1>Page 1 content goes here...</h1>
        <div class="outer">
          <div class="inner" sizer>
             {{ zoom }}
          </div>
      </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.router']);

myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.when("", "/PageTab");

    $stateProvider
        .state("PageTab", {
            url: "/PageTab",
            templateUrl: "PageTab.html"
        })
        .state("PageTab.Page1", {
            url: "/Page1",
            templateUrl: "Page1.html"
        })
        .state("PageTab.Page2", {
            url: "/Page2",
            templateUrl: "Page2.html"
         })
        .state("PageTab.Page3", {
            url: "/Page3",
            templateUrl: "Page3.html"
        });
});

myApp.directive('sizer', function($window) {
        return {
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

              scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
                  scope.zoom = elem[0].clientWidth / 674;
              });

              //watch window resize
              angular.element($window).bind('resize', function () {
                  scope.zoom = elem[0].clientWidth / 674;
                  scope.$apply();
              });
            }
        };
    });
```